# is there a lint rule to enforce React components always return?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint, lint

Sometimes I forget the return statement in a React component, like:

```
function Cat() { <div>Meow</div> }
// should be
function Cat() { return <div>Meow</div> }
```

This results in the error:

```
Cat(...): Nothing was returned from render
```

is there a lint rule to warn me about that?

Comment: Not necessarily what you're looking for, but if you use typescript, you'd get a type error:

`const Cat: React.FC = () => { <div>Meow</div>; }` gives error `Type '() => void' is not assignable to type 'FC<{}>'. ...`

Comment: I guess, but there's no way to enforce that on `function`.

Comment: You can still use `function` in typescript, I just slightly changed the syntax. `function Cat(): React.FC { <div>Meow</div> }` gives the same error.

Comment: not quite. I could do `function Cat(): ReactElement | null { ... }` which is not as nice, but definitely works. No lint rule though?